# What noun describes the relationship between a container and a containee?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

For example, the relationship between two things that overlap is called or is described by their "overlap" or "intersection".

What word or words might have the same role in describing the relationship between a thing and a thing it contains?

*Failing that, is there a word or words that describe the phenomenon instead of the relationship? I'd also be open to replacing "contains" with "is a superset of", "completely covers", or "starts before and ends after".*

Comment: *Containment* : The act or condition of containing. http://www.thefreedictionary.com/containment

Comment: Containment is great. *Packaging* might be work in some situations, too.

Comment: Freight, for example, can be [*containered*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22containered%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), leading to the gerund noun [*containering*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22containering%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1).

Comment: @Josh61: Please post *containment* as an answer. It is the obvious (and probably best) answer.

Comment: @FumbleFingers isn't *containering* an action, though?  I am unfamiliar with the term, but without context, I assume *to container* means *to load into a container.*

Comment: @Drew - 'containment' is ***an*** answer but it isn't ***the*** answer according to most dictionaries. "containment" is a specialist term that usually refers to "the action of keeping something harmful under control or within limits" -  Google Dictionary

Comment: @chaslyfromUK: That that might be the more common meaning of this word does not imply that this word is not the best - or even the most common - word to express **this** meaning. *Choir*, for example, refers most commonly to a group of singers, but it is also the best word for a particular area of a church:  the part of the chancel between the sanctuary and the nave.

Answer (score 1):

subsumption

comprisal

enclosure

encompassment

inclusion

subset

Comment: Please provide links and definitions. A simple list of terms is not a useful answer.

Comment: But the tag is *single-word requests*. I've given a list of single words (!?)

Comment: Yes, but what do they mean? Could any of them answer the question or are there substantial differences in meaning? Do you think one of them could actually fit more then the others? That's why  links and definitions are very important . Plus remember that there are a number of non-native speakers who may not be familiar with the terms.

Answer (score 0):

This is more relevant for programming scenarios, but in some cases you could use **aggregation** (multiple containees of *same* type) or **composition** (containees of *different* types).

Also, a container implies that it will ***enclose*** or ***envelop*** its contents.

Comment: While an automobile is definitely composed of wheels, tires, an engine, and so forth, and therefore comprises those parts, I don't think of that compose/comprise relationship as one of *containment* but rather as one of, well, *composition.*  Would you say that a motorcycle contains two wheels?  I would not.  (This points out the importance of the concept of enclosure that you mention in your last sentence.)